# highcharts datalabel per point with different format

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

i have a highcharts chart with 2 different lines (y axis). i want to enable dataLabels for both, however, with different formatting. the labels of the first line should be `x °C` and the labels of the second line should be `y mb`. i am aware that `dataLabels` can be enabled via `enabled = true`, and that there is a `formatter` parameter which can set the custom formatting.

my problem is that i do not know how/where i can set this for each point on a line.

i set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cha9ugqu/

the result should be like this (the lables should - obviously - appear) at each datapoint:
[image: expected result]

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, i just solved it.

i have to add the `dataLabels` at the series.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/cha9ugqu/1/

Comment: In your example, it shows dataLabel for all the points. What if we only want to display data label on the first point, any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: I know this thread is old, but I will leave an answer here for @CristusCleetus question, you can modify the formatter function in the dataLabels object for this purposes:  `formatter: function() {  if (this.point.index == 0) {  return this.y + ' mb';  }  }  }`

Comment: @AlbertoRechy Thanks for the comment! :D, yes that does it!